# How To solve Program.num1/num2 is never assign to, and will always have its default value 0;

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace Myprog
{

class Myprog
{
    int num1;
    int num2;

    public void Getdata()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("enter two numbers");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public void Showdata()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First value {0} Second value {1}",num1,num2);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Myprog C=new Myprog();
        C.Getdata();
        C.Showdata();
    }
}
}
```

=>in this program always assign value 0, please give me suggestion how to solve this program and I want to run to this program in this manner.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this because you always enter a smaller value first?

Comment: so what is the right code to solve this problem??

Comment: Use a type other than `int` for your variables.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think `Program.num1/num2` part is not a division in the title. Since there is no operation `num1/num2` in OP's code, I think he try to say like  `Program.num1 and num2 is never assigned...` etc.

Comment: right way is remove int in Getdata()

Answer (score 3):

Your `num1` and `num2` as a fields are *completely* different your `num1` and `num2` as a local variables.

You can assign those variables into your fields in your `Getdata` method like;

```
this.num1 = num1;
this.num2 = num2;
```

like;

```
int num1;
int num2;

public void Getdata()
{   
    Console.WriteLine("enter two numbers");
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
}
public void Showdata()
{
    Console.WriteLine("First vale {0} Second value {1}",num1,num2);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Myprog C=new Myprog();
    C.Getdata();
    C.Showdata();
}
```

Comment: there is error :cant use local variable ' num1 ' before it declare err cs0844

Comment: @rohittech Have you tried complete code that I posted?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Getdata()` method you define new local variables named `num1` and `num2` and assign values to them.

Remove the `int` from each line to assign values to fields `num1` and `num2` instead of creating locals.

```
num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Yes this method resolve my problem thanks Jakub Lortz